# Correct implementation of refreshtoken with ApolloClient

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I am trying to refresh the authentication token when it is near the expiration time, however I end up with an endless loop. The expectation is that the code that checks the expiration time in **App.js** should work and reset the auth token and the refresh token, however is starts looping endlessly.

I have the following **Auth helper functions**:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../models/User");
const { AuthenticationError } = require("apollo-server-express");
const config = require("config");
const jwtSecret = config.get("jwt_secret");
const jwtRefreshTokenSecret = config.get("jwt_refresh_token");

const authFunctions = {
  checkSignedIn: async (req, requireAuth = true) => {
    const header = req.headers.authorization;
    if (header) {
      const token = header.replace("Bearer ", "");
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret);
      console.log(decoded);
      let user = await User.findById(decoded.id);
      if (!user) {
        throw new AuthenticationError("Invalid user credentials.");
      }
      return user;
    }
    if (requireAuth) {
      throw new AuthenticationError("You must be logged in.");
    }
    return null;
  },
  issueToken: async (user) => {
    let token = "Bearer " + (await authFunctions.createToken(user));
    let refreshToken = await authFunctions.createToken(user, 100);
    return { token, refreshToken };
  },
  issueNewToken: async (req) => {
    try {
      const token = req.headers.refreshtoken;
      if (token) {
        const decoded = await jwt.verify(token, jwtRefreshTokenSecret);
        let user = await User.findById(decoded.id);
        console.log(user);
        if (!user) {
          throw new AuthenticationError("No user found.");
        }
        let tokens = await authFunctions.issueToken(user);
        return { ...tokens, user };
      }
    } catch (err) {
      throw new AuthenticationError("Invalid Refresh Token.");
    }
  },
  createToken: async ({ id, address }, expiresIn = 60) => {
    let secret = expiresIn === 60 ? jwtSecret : jwtRefreshTokenSecret;
    return await jwt.sign({ id, address }, secret, { expiresIn });
  },
};

module.exports = authFunctions;
```

The **schema**:

```
const { gql } = require("apollo-server");

const typeDefs = gql`
  scalar Date
  scalar MongoId

  type User {
    _id: MongoId!
    address: String!
    createdAt: Date
  }

  type Auth {
    user: User!
    token: String!
    refreshToken: String!
  }

  input LoginInput {
    address: String!
  }

  type Query {
    refreshTokens: Auth!
  }

  type Mutation {
    createOrGetUser(loginInput: LoginInput): Auth!
  }
`;

module.exports = typeDefs;
```

The **resolvers**:

```
const User = require("../../models/User");
const {
  issueToken,
  issueNewToken,
  checkSignedIn,
} = require("../../middleware/Auth");

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    refreshTokens: async (root, args, { req }, info) =>
      await issueNewToken(req),
  },

  Mutation: {
    createOrGetUser: async (root, args, { req }, info) => {
      try {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({
          address: args.loginInput.address,
        })
          .populate({
            path: "orders",
            model: Order,
          })
          .exec();

        if (existingUser) {
          let tokens = await issueToken(existingUser);

          return {
            user: existingUser,
            ...tokens,
          };
        }
        const user = await new User({
          address: args.loginInput.address,
        });
        const result = await user.save();

        let tokens = await issueToken(result);

        return {
          user,
          ...tokens,
        };
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    },
  },
};

module.exports = resolvers;
```

And the **App.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloLink,
  createHttpLink,
  useReactiveVar,
  concat,
} from "@apollo/client";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client/react";
import { accessTokenVar, isLoggedInVar } from "./cache";
import cache from "./cache.js";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

// Styling
import "./styles/App.css";

// Components
import Routes from "./components/routing/Routes";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/Navbar";
import { REFRESH_TOKENS } from "./queries/User";

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: "/graphql",
});

const refreshTokens = () => {
  return client.query({ query: REFRESH_TOKENS }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    // Need to set the token to cache here, but the query doesn't get executed it seems

    //accessTokenVar(response.data)
    return;
  });
};

const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  // add the authorization to the headers
  let token = accessTokenVar();
  if (token) {
    token = token.replace("Bearer ", "");
    const { exp } = jwtDecode(token);
    console.log(exp);
    // Refresh the token a minute early to avoid latency issues
    const expirationTime = exp - 30;
    if (Date.now() / 1000 >= expirationTime) {
      refreshTokens(); // this keeps going on a loop
    }
  }

  operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => ({
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? token : "",
    },
  }));

  return forward(operation);
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: concat(authMiddleware, httpLink),
  connectToDevTools: true,
  credentials: "include",
});

const App = () => {
  const accessToken = useReactiveVar(accessTokenVar);
  const isLoggedIn = useReactiveVar(isLoggedInVar);

  //let isLoggedIn;
  accessToken ? isLoggedInVar(true) : isLoggedInVar(false);

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router>
        <Fragment>
          <Navbar isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
        </Fragment>
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Note:** When `createOrGetUser` is executed the first time, the flow works. Then, I wait for 30 seconds and send a protected query, after which it gets in an endless loop.

Overall, I feel this flow is broken somehow, but I can't figure out what exactly. Would appreciate any help with this!